# Query for Records Where Exists Having Max(Date)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, exists, having

I'm trying to create a query to find a thread that has *at least one record with a date less than* 20 minutes old

This is for a heartbeat table that looks like this:

```
+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| heartbeat_id | server_id | thread              | last_checkin        |
+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|            3 |       133 | EscalationMonitor   | 2016-03-16 23:46:07 |
|            7 |       133 | EmailMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:47:31 |
|           11 |       133 | TableMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:42:49 |
|           15 |       133 | NotificationMonitor | 2016-03-16 23:46:30 |
|           19 |       127 | EmailMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:47:21 |
|           23 |       127 | TableMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:46:11 |
|           27 |       127 | EscalationMonitor   | 2016-03-16 23:47:58 |
|           31 |       127 | NotificationMonitor | 2016-03-16 23:41:10 |
|           35 |       123 | EmailMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:47:59 |
|           39 |       123 | TableMonitor        | 2016-03-16 23:43:10 |
|           43 |       123 | EscalationMonitor   | 2016-03-16 23:46:26 |
|           47 |       123 | NotificationMonitor | 2016-03-16 23:46:47 |
+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is where I am, but this searches for *at least one record more than* 20 minutes old.

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat h WHERE exists
(
    select * from heartbeat h2
    where last_checkin < date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 20 MINUTE)
)
group by thread
```

Comment: remove `-` from `INTERVAL - 20 MINUTE`

Comment: That would mean last_checkin < 20 minutes in the future...right?

Comment: no, it will be older than `20` minutes from creation dates

Comment: lets say your records have been added to your table, they must have creation date, so this will check records that have been inserted since 20 minutes ago only

Comment: Lets say it is `23:59` now. And take example of `EmailMonitor`.  Your current query gives you `7,133,EmailMonitor, 2016-03-16 23:47:31`. What do you expect for `EmainMonitor` and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want threads that have at least 1 checkin more than 20 minutes ago, you can put that condition in the where clause and use distinct to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct thread from heartbeat
where last_checkin > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
```

To retrieve all threads that have no check-ins less than 20 minutes old:

```
select thread from heartbeat
group by thread
having count(case when last_checkin > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) then 1 end) = 0
```

If you have a `threads` table, then you can take advantage of `not exists`

```
select * from threads t where not exists (
  select 1 from heartbeat h
  where t.thread = h.thread
  and h.last_checkin >  date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
)
```

Comment: I want threads that have at least 1 checkin less than 20 minutes old. Put another way, I want threads that have no checkins more than 20 minutes old. (Actually, this will be fore a monitoring cron, which will invoke alerts if there are records in the result set. So "No Records Less Than 20 Minutes Old" would be the right way of putting this.)

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber updated the query but these are not the same. suppose a thread has a checkin 15 minutes ago as well as 40 minutes ago. That would fulfill the 1st criteria but not the second.

Comment: Yeeeess, that query "having count(...) = 0" is the one I'm looking for. Thanks @FuzzyTree

Answer (score 0):

remove `-` from `INTERVAL - 20 MINUTE`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11661682)

Comment: I have provided the trick to his question and explained it in comment, then Fuzzy has used my trick to re-correct his first answer

Comment: It needed date_sub for that to work. date_add(now(), interval - 20 minute) is, I think, synonymous with date_sub(now(), interval 20 minute).